# Parallel Processing in SAS

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, sas, sas-macro, proc-sql

oh wise StackOverflow users. I have a question about parallel processing in SAS 9.4:

I'm aware that SAS typically executes procedures in a sequential, or linear manner, however, I am also aware that SAS is capable of executing procedures in parallel as well. My question is: How do you set this up? I've checked several blogs and I've not had any degree of success. The general layout of my code is this:

```
MACRO VARIABLES;
%syslput _all_;
RSubmit;
Data step to slightly modify variables;
Run;
EndRSubmit;

PROC SQL 1;
Connect to server statement;
SQL code;
QUIT;
...
PROC SQL n;
Connect to server statement;
SQL code;
QUIT;
```

There are 8 pieces of PROC SQL code that I would ideally like to execute in parallel, rather than in linear fashion. Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite threadding, but if you're able to use RSUBMIT there's an option where the code is sent and then you have control of your computer again. You still have to wait for the output but it doesn't han up or hold up your computer.

```
RSUBMIT CONNECTWAIT=NO;
```

Not sure if you need a slash after the RSUBMIT, but nothing shows in the documentation.

https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=connref&docsetTarget=p1eyablk3vvdlkn1h5euyczvt585.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en

Comment: You don't need the `/` :)

Answer (score 0):

Provided your code pieces are independent, you can submit them and run in parallel in separate SAS sessions. Even though these sessions are called "remote" you can run them even on a single machine. Here is an example of one "remote" session:

```
/* Prosess 1 */
signon task1;
rsubmit task1 wait=no;

   PROC SQL n;
   Connect to server statement;
   SQL code;
   QUIT;

endrsubmit;
```

You can have multiple such RSUBMIT/ENDRSUBMIT sessions.

At the end you need to synchronize your results using

```
waitfor _all_;
signoff _all_;
```

You may find detailed explanation of this method in [Running SAS programs in parallel using SAS/CONNECT®](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2021/01/13/running-sas-programs-in-parallel-using-sas-connect/) blog post.